# C# - Organizing a list of lists by the number of values they contain - C#

Tags: c#, list

Hey Im trying to solve a coding problem.
I want to find the biggest collatz sequenz with the starting value under 1 million.
In a collatz sequenz the starting value getsdivided by 2 if its an even number and gets multiplied by 3, + 1 if its an uneven number.
For that I want to make a for-loop with a while(i != 1) loop an to if-statements to do the equations. for each number i I want to make a new list and put each one inside of another list. Then I want to orgnize them by the number of values they contain, so that I can then return the largest sequenz.
Can any body tell me how ican acomplish this in c#.
I am very thankfull for your help.

```
    for(int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        while (i != 1)
        {
            List<int> z = new List<int>();
            z.Add(i);
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                i = i / 2;
                z.Add((int)i);
            }
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                i = i * 3 + 1;
                z.Add((int)i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: doesn't the above do what you want? You should provide some sample input and the expected outcome.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain not yet, it creates a list with the values for each sequenz. but it just makes one very long list and I dont know how to make a list in a list for the sequenz of each starting value. Neither do i know how to organize them by their length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var listOfLists = new List<List<int>>();
for(int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    while (i != 1)
    {
         List<int> z = new List<int>();
         ...
    }     
    listOfLists.Add(z);
}
...
var largest = listOfLists.MaxBy(list => list.Count);
var ordered = listOfLists.OrderByDescending(list => list.Count).ToList();
```